# how to implement substring() in db_select statement

Tags: 7, database

I am porting a drupal 6 module to drupal 7. I came across this SQL query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM {counter} WHERE SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10)= '%s'
```

How to implement the same query in db_select. db_select() will have substring() in its condition clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple quick greps suggest something like this...

```
$query->where('SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10) = :arg', array(':arg' => $arg));
```

...should do it.

Comment: thanks, and suppose i want to use AND logical operator in where clause. how to do it?

Comment: everything is perfect except that there wont be any double quotes "" around the placeholder

Comment: I was wondering about those :)

Answer (score 3):

The alternative, if `$query` is the object returned from `db_select()`, is to use expressions as reported in [Dynamic queries, Expressions](http://drupal.org/node/310075#expressions).

```
$substring_alias = $query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10)', 'counter_substring');
```

`$substring_alias` can be used then in `$query->condition()`, such as in the following code.

```
$query->condition($substring_alias, $value);
```

In this way you can use the condition together other ones. By default, conditions are ANDed together; if you need to OR them together, you can use the following code.

```
$query->condition(db_or()
  ->condition($substring_alias, $value)
  ->condition(/* the other condition */)
);
```

The value returned from `$query->addExpression()` is the alias effectively used for the expression; the method tries to use the alias passed as second argument, but if that alias is already used, it will generate a new alias.

`$query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10)', 'counter_substring')` alone is equivalent to the following select statement.

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10) AS counter_substring
```

In `$query->addExpression('SUBSTRING(counter_date,1,10)', 'counter_substring')`, I supposed there is not a "counter_substring" field defined for the database table; in the case there is that field, you should use a different alias. The documentation says the method is able to use a different alias, if the proposed one is already in use, but it doesn't say what the behavior of the method is, when there is a field with that exact name; I would not expect the method verifies the alias is not a field name, before to use it.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to work in MySQL. It complains that the alias does not exist. It looks like for SUBSTRING it should be done with a WHERE (or that I misunderstood something).